# Never seen Chespin :(

Tags: pokemon-x-y

So I just completed the game, and I decided that I wanted to complete my pokédex! So I went to go evolve my fennekin (the one you get from your friend after the Pokemon league, it could also be froakie or chespin depending on what your starter is) so it evolves to Braixen. I looked at my pokédex— and wtf? How have I never seen a Chespin? Idk how I never saw one, but can you help me please? I am soooo confused!

Comment: Are you asking where to find one?

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to get a Chespin.

- As a starter Pokémon in X/Y
- Trade with Shauna after you beat the Elite 4 and you have Fennekin as starter
- Trade from GTS

Comment: Also breed a Quilladin if you have a friend safari with those.

Comment: @Jerry he's probably going to have to breed since I don't think you can search for a pokemon on GTS if you've never seen them.

Comment: @BooleanCheese You can search for any Pokemon on the GTS as long as you can spell its name properly (though you can't specify gender with this search, which is weird).